# Android map change tile overlays without clear()

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a map with multiple map types that you can choose from (default Google Maps Tiles (online), OSM tiles (offline), My other custom map(offline)).

Also I have 394 markers on the map (but it's just a small map of ONE town... not important)

The problem is, it's posiible to change between google map types, because theres function for it, without clearing the map and creating and inserting markers all over again.

But if I select for example OSM map tiles, they're added like Overlay, so when I want to change them to another map, including Google Maps, I have to call mMap.clear() and then add all markers and different map tiles or change type of google map.

I know it's possible to delete specific marker by saving it in variable and then call remove() on it. Is there something similar with map overlays?

I add map tile overlays like this:

```
mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new CustomMapTileProvider(m_context,MAP_TYPE_OSM)));
```

Comment: Nevermind, I kind of find it out while writing the question. Solved it like with the markers. Created TileOverlay variable where I was able to save the TileOverlay and then call remove() on it, just like markers. I don't know how could I missed that.

Comment: Thank you @(Zdeněk Braun), I had missed this simple solution too. I suggest you post a regular answer to your own question, and select it as "accepted answer", so you will benefit from the reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The thread opener has solved his question himself:*

You need to **store the return value of the gmap.addTileOverlay()** method to a variable and can **then call .remove() on it** (just as you would with markers):

```java
public class Map {
    private TileOverlay tileOverlay;
    ...

    void replaceOverlayTiles() {

        TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            String s = String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "http://www.domain.com/xyz_tiles/%d/%d/%d.png", zoom, x, y);

            if (!checkTileExists(x, y, zoom))
                return null;

            try {
                return new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }

        private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            return !(zoom < 0 || zoom > 20);
        }
    };

    if (tileOverlay != null)
        tileOverlay.remove();

    tileOverlay = googleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().fadeIn(false).tileProvider(tileProvider));
}
```